# How to store C# SpecialFolder path into SQLite database?

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I am working on a WPF app and I am stuck in a tricky problem.

There is a `TEXT` field called "OutputFolder" into SQLite database which stores different folder paths (as name suggests its folder where some output is generated).

I want to save special folder path (`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)`) into `SQLite` database in "OutputFolder".

Actual value I want to store in database

`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\temp";`

I have no option to use any other directory or something else. Its very clear that I have to store this path into database.

I am open to add new column to specify any flag value or anything that identify path as special folder.

Comment: I don't follow the question. when you + "\\temp" to that getfolderpath, you get a string. Isn't the answer to just store it in OutputFolder with some key so you can find it again? But I don't follow why you need to store it at all anyhow.

Comment: @Andy Thanks for response. **1.** I do getfolderpath + "\\temp" in C#. Currently is static code I put for testing. But there are other paths as well in same DB field. **2.** There is a third party service which generates result at that particular location and there is no way I can change that. Its pre-compiled service.

Comment: What I do not understand is why you don't just write the generated path to the DB?

Comment: @Hille No path is generating. I need to read path from DB and use it into app. In DB, "OutputFolder" field contains both static paths and special folder path as values. I hope you get. I am Open for other questions.

Comment: Do you want to store `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\temp";` or `C:\User\...\temp`?

Comment: I want to store `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\temp";`

Comment: Who does write the path to the DB and who does read?

Comment: @Rekshino WPF (this) app writes and reads.

Answer (score 1):

As I have understood - you need to store both types of paths absolute and one containing special folders. The problem is how to recognize a type of path and then to handle it accordingly.

If you can't change the db data structure(to add additional fields), then probably is a way to inject information about special folder into the path.

E.g. you can use invalid(for path) characters to mark start and end of injection. Your path should then looks like:

```
var injectedPath = "?5?\\temp";
```

Of course on read you have to parse and if an injection being found replace it with real path. In our case MyDocuments = 5 see [Environment.SpecialFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Thanks for response. You understood exactly what I needed!.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, **Rekshino**'s answer can be one of the way to achieve this.

Mean while I solved this.

As mentioned in question,

> I am open to add new column to specify any flag value or anything that
>   identify path as special folder.

**Implemented Solution**

DB Fields:

`OutputFolder` = Path of directory (static path or remaining path under special folder)

`IsSpecialOutputFolder` = Flag to identify where current path has any special folder or not.

`SpecialFolderId` = Enum value of `Environment.SpecialFolder`. (In our case MyDocuments = 5). I set default value to -1 as it is not value of any item in `Environment.SpecialFolder` enum.

See [Environment.SpecialFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netframework-4.8) for more detail for this `enum`.

UI:

[image]

Code behind info:

`DropDown` to give more `Environment.SpecialFolder` selection to user. Bind following `Dictionary<int, string>` to it. In future, it will allow to add more items.

```
public static Dictionary<int, string> AllowedSpecialFolders = new Dictionary<int, string>() 
{
    {0,"Desktop" }, {5, "MyDocuments"}
};
```

`CheckBox` check/uncheck makes `DropDown` enabled and disabled.

Implemented proper validation where special folder path entered and static path entered. 
Example: In case of special path, remaining directory path must not contain any root directory.

```
if (IsSpecialOutputFolder)
{
    // ALL OTHER PROCESSING AND VALIDATIONS HERE.
}
```